# How to properly perform a SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT moduloT.diagnostico FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloT AS moduloT WHERE moduloT.idPaciente=612) AS moduloT,
    (SELECT CASE WHEN moduloU.preguntaU8 = 'Si' OR moduloU.preguntaU9 = 'Si' THEN 'Si' ELSE 'No' END FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloU AS moduloU WHERE moduloU.idPaciente=612) AS moduloU,
    (SELECT moduloW.diagnostico FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloW AS moduloW WHERE moduloW.idPaciente=612) AS moduloW,
    (SELECT moduloX.diagnostico FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloX AS moduloX WHERE moduloX.idPaciente=612) AS moduloX,
    (SELECT moduloY.diagnostico FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloY AS moduloY WHERE moduloY.idPaciente=612) AS moduloY;
```

I get this result:

> The subquery returned more than one value, which is not correct when followed by =,! =, <, <=,>,> = Or when used as an expression.

I do not understand why it is due and how to correct it, I would greatly appreciate it if you could give me an idea of ​​how to solve it.

Comment: You are trying to use 5 select statements as sub-queries in an outer select, one of your sub-queries is returning more than one value. To be able to assist we need to see some sample data and desired results.

Comment: Each of your subqueries can return at most 1 value. It seems one or more of those tables contain multiple records matching `idPaciente = 612`.

Comment: You're going to have to run each of the subqueries by itself to figure out which of them is returning more than one row, and then figure out how to change the WHERE clause to make it specific enough that it only returns one row. The error message tells you exactly what is wrong (*The subquery returned more than one value*). WIth that being said, you need to provide sample data and the output you want to obtain from that data, so that you've provided a [mre] that demonstrates the issue if you want us to help.

Comment: Thank you, it was resolved correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another option is to re-write the queries as a JOIN ... Perhaps multiple records should be expected.

**Example**

```
Select moduloT = T.diagnostico
      ,moduloU = CASE WHEN U.preguntaU8 = 'Si' OR U.preguntaU9 = 'Si' THEN 'Si' ELSE 'No' END
      ,moduloW = W.diagnostico
      ,moduloX = X.diagnostico
      ,moduloY = Y.diagnostico
 From  BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloT T
 Left Join  BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloU U on T.idPaciente = U.idPaciente
 Left Join  BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloW W on T.idPaciente = W.idPaciente
 Left Join  BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloX X on T.idPaciente = X.idPaciente
 Left Join  BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloY Y on T.idPaciente = Y.idPaciente
 Where T.idPaciente=612
```

Answer (score -1):

Like @Dale K and @AlwaysLearning commented, your sub-queries can return more than one record.

So if you want a unique record with the MAX diagnostico:

```
SELECT
(SELECT MAX(moduloT.diagnostico) FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloT AS moduloT WHERE moduloT.idPaciente=612) AS moduloT,
(SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(moduloU.preguntaU8) = 'Si' OR MAX(moduloU.preguntaU9) = 'Si' THEN 'Si' ELSE 'No' END FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloU AS moduloU WHERE moduloU.idPaciente=612) AS moduloU,
(SELECT MAX(moduloW.diagnostico) FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloW AS moduloW WHERE moduloW.idPaciente=612) AS moduloW,
(SELECT MAX(moduloX.diagnostico) FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloX AS moduloX WHERE moduloX.idPaciente=612) AS moduloX,
(SELECT MAX(moduloY.diagnostico) FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloY AS moduloY WHERE moduloY.idPaciente=612) AS moduloY;
```

Or if you want to retrieve all the records, you can use join:

```
SELECT 'T' AS modulo, moduloT.diagnostico AS diagnostico FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloT AS moduloT WHERE moduloT.idPaciente=612
UNION ALL
SELECT 'U' AS modulo, CASE WHEN moduloU.preguntaU8 = 'Si' OR moduloU.preguntaU9 = 'Si' THEN 'Si' ELSE 'No' END AS diagnostico FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloU AS moduloU WHERE moduloU.idPaciente=612
UNION ALL
SELECT 'W' AS modulo, moduloW.diagnostico AS diagnostico FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloW AS moduloW WHERE moduloW.idPaciente=612
UNION ALL
SELECT 'X' AS modulo, moduloX.diagnostico FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloX AS moduloX WHERE moduloX.idPaciente=612
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y' AS modulo, moduloY.diagnostico FROM BdMINIPlus.dbo.moduloY AS moduloY WHERE moduloY.idPaciente=612
```

Either way, provide us some sample data so we can help you.